# Stop Nativescript from using webpack

Tags: webpack, cross-platform, nativescript, bundle, uninstallation

i am developing a projet useing nativescript and angular.

at release stage i tried to use webpack to optimaze my project but since i am new with webpack i got million of errors so i tried to delete webpack from package.json then i deleted the hooks, platforms and node_modules folders 
and when i retried to install the app in my phone but this time didn't work and i got this error

> Passing --bundle requires a bundling plugin. No bundling plugin found or the specified bundling plugin is invalid

what i want to do is stop webpack completely from working and back to normal mode without losing my work or my projet 
thank you

Comment: Just do not pass `--bundle` parameter, that's what decides whether or not to use webpack.

Comment: i did so but i got this error that's why i asked how to stop it

Comment: If you are using v5.4 or later, webpack is default now unless you disable it by setting `useLegacyWorkflow` to `true` on `nsconfig.json`

Comment: Cool, thanks for confirming. Have added same as an answer.

Comment: @medfarjallah, the Webpack workflow will be the ONLY way of building apps starting from NativeScript 6.0. I highly recommend you investigate your Webpack build issues and log the errors at https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues

Answer (score 0):

Prior to {N} v5.4, webpack was not default. You had to pass `--bundle` option for webpack build.

Since v5.4, webpack became default & recommended. Still you may choose to disable webpack by setting `useLegacyWorkflow` to `true` in `nsconfig.json`

Answer (score 0):

Using the LegacyWorkflow workaround is just a temporary solution as the Webpack workflow will become [the ONLY way of building apps starting from NativeScript 6.0.](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/the-future-of-building-nativescript-apps)

I highly recommend you investigate your Webpack build errors and [log any issues here](http://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues).